# Hadoop Installation in Windows 7

Tags: windows, hadoop

I am working on hadoop installation in Windows 7.

Tried to untar the tarfiles from apache site but it was unsuccessful.

I have searched in internet and found below link.

```
http://toodey.com/2015/08/10/hadoop-installation-on-windows-without-cygwin-in-10-mints/
```

I was able to install. But when i was trying to execute the examples i was encountered with below errors.

Command executed :

```
C:\Users\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1\bin\hadoop.cmd jar C:\Users\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar  wordcount /hadoop/input /hadoop/output
```

Error :

```
C:\Users\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1>C:\Users\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1\bin\hadoop.cmd jar C:\Users\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar  wordcount /hadoop/input /hadoop/output
16/11/14 17:05:28 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:0000
16/11/14 17:05:30 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
16/11/14 17:05:30 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:3
16/11/14 17:05:30 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1479122512555_0003
16/11/14 17:05:31 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1479122512555_0003
16/11/14 17:05:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://MachineName:8088/proxy/application_1479122512555_0003/
16/11/14 17:05:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1479122512555_0003
16/11/14 17:05:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1479122512555_0003 running in uber mode : false
16/11/14 17:05:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/11/14 17:05:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1479122512555_0003 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1479122512555_0003 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1479122512555_0003_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://MachineName:8088/cluster/app/application_1479122512555_0003Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: null
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
16/11/14 17:05:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is due to the permission issues on some of the yarn local directories. So here is the solution

- Identify the yarn directories specified using the parameter yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs from /etc/gphd/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml on yarn node manager.
- Delete the files / folders under usercache from all the directories listed in yarn-site.xml and all the node managers.

e.g

```
rmdir path/to/yarn/nm/usercache/*
```

Comment: Below is the message i can see..

No logs available for container container_1479122512555_0003_02_000001

Let me know if i am pointing wrong log.

Comment: Always give specific file name for input

Comment: Now i have executed below.

C:\Users\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1\bin\hadoop.cmd jar C:\Users\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar  wordcount /hadoop/input/LICENSE.txt /hadoop/output

But error is trill the same.

May i know whether there is any problem with installation?

Comment: Well without details of log file, its very difficult to tell.Once again refer this link ,which will guide you to see  stderr  container log file http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/46/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-service-compositeservice-shell-exitcodeexception-classnotfoundexception )

Comment: Please find the details requested....



Application application_1479130023968_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1479130023968_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://MachineName:8088/cluster/app/application_1479130023968_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: null
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.

Comment: Below is some what i have found in Resource Manager Log

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.channelRead(Server.java:2603)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Below is the configuration in yarn-site.xml

    <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
    <value>/user/namenode</value>
   </property>

But i dont see any files or folders created as usercache ...

Comment: Below is the error in Node Manager..

16/11/17 19:30:45 ERROR nodemanager.DeletionService: Exception during execution of task in DeletionService
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.fixRelativePart(FileContext.java:274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.delete(FileContext.java:761)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DeletionService$FileDeletionTask.run(DeletionService.java:272)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)